# Calling a webservice MS .Net using PHP and cURL to a function that's exposed and returning the values

Tags: php, xml, curl, post, soap

This has been more difficult than I expected. I'm trying to call a function called `Get_Item_Quantity` and return it's params. The params i'm trying to return are

Function name: Get_Item_Quantity
This function takes `Type`, `Code` fields and returns `Qty1, Qty2, Qty3,` and `Qty4`
Parameters:

```
Type = 0 – input value
Code = ‘product100317’ – input value
Qty 1 – return value
Qty 2 – return value
Qty 3 – return value
Qty 4 – return value
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php

namespace Test\CustomApi\Model\Api;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Custom
{
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getQty($type, $code, $qty1, $qty2, $qty3, $qty4) {
        $response = ['success' => false];

        try {
            // Logic to call soap service here
            $qty = $this->getItemQty($type, $code, $qty1, $qty2, $qty3, $qty4);
            $response = ['success' => true, 'qty' => $qty];

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $response = ['success' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage()];
            $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
        }

        $returnArray = json_encode($response);
        return $returnArray;
    }


    /**
     * Soap API call 
     *
     * @param int $type
     * @param string $code
     * @param string $qty1
     * @param string $qty2
     * @param string $qty3
     * @param string $qty4
     * @return void
     */
    public function getItemQty($type, $code, $qty1, $qty2, $qty3, $qty4)
    {
        $soapRequest = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
          <soap12:Body>
          <APIDataCapture>
            <Get_Item_Quantity xmlns="URLwheresoapxmlexists">
                <Type>' . $type . '</Type>
                <Code>' . $code . '</Code>
                <qty1>' . $qty1 . '</qty1>
                <qty2>' . $qty2 . '</qty2>
                <qty3>' . $qty3 . '</qty3>
                <qty4>' . $qty4 . '</qty4>
            </Get_Item_Quantity>
            </APIDataCapture>
          </soap12:Body>
        </soap12:Envelope>';
        $header = array(
            "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
            "Accept: text/xml",
        );
        $soapHandler = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1');
        curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_URL, "URLwheresoapxmlexists");
        curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
        curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $soapRequest);
        curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
        //header('Content-type: text/xml');
        $result = curl_exec($soapHandler);
        $qtyData = array();
        if ($result === false) {
            $err = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($soapHandler);
            curl_close($soapHandler);
            $this->logger->info($err);
        } else {
            curl_close($soapHandler);
            $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
            $xml->registerXPathNamespace('soap', 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope');
            $result = $xml->xpath('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body');
            $res = $result[0]->Get_Item_Quantity_Result;
            $qtyData = simplexml_load_string($res);
        }
        return $qtyData;
    }
}
```

When I run a POST request in postman i receive this back.

```
"{\"success\":true,\"qty\":[]}"
```

[image]

Here is the SOAP XML document with the exposed function:

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/myWSAPI"
             targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/myWSAPI">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x00000"
                elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x00000">
            <complexType name="APIDataCapture">
                <sequence>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Type" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Code" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Qty1" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Qty2" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Qty3" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Qty4" type="string"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
            <complexType name="Root" mixed="true">
                <sequence>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="APIDataCapture" type="tns:APIDataCapture"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
            <element name="Root" type="tns:Root"/>
        </schema>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x50014"
                elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x50014">
            <complexType name="APIDataCapture">
                <sequence>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Type" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" default="0" name="EntryNo" type="int"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SalesOrderFound" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SalesOrderNo" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" default="0" name="SalesOrderLineNo" type="int"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SalesOrderETADate" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SalesOrderItemNo" type="string"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
            <complexType name="Root" mixed="true">
                <sequence>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="APIDataCapture" type="tns:APIDataCapture"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
            <element name="Root" type="tns:Root"/>
        </schema>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
                targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/MyWSAPI">
            <element name="Get_Item_ETA_Date">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="itemNo" type="string"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="Get_Item_ETA_Date_Result">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="return_value" type="date"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="custNo" type="string"/>
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="extDocNo" type="string"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No_Result">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="return_value" type="boolean"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="Get_Item_Quantity">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element xmlns:q1="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x00000" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
                                 name="aPIDataCapture" type="q1:Root"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="Get_Item_Quantity_Result">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element xmlns:q2="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x00000" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
                                 name="aPIDataCapture" type="q2:Root"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="GetSalesOrderETA">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element xmlns:q3="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x50014" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
                                 name="aPIDataCapture" type="q3:Root"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="GetSalesOrderETA_Result">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element xmlns:q4="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x50014" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
                                 name="aPIDataCapture" type="q4:Root"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
        </schema>
    </types>
    <message name="Get_Item_ETA_Date">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Get_Item_ETA_Date"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Get_Item_ETA_Date_Result">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Get_Item_ETA_Date_Result"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No_Result">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No_Result"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Get_Item_Quantity">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Get_Item_Quantity"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Get_Item_Quantity_Result">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Get_Item_Quantity_Result"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetSalesOrderETA">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:GetSalesOrderETA"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetSalesOrderETA_Result">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:GetSalesOrderETA_Result"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="MyWSAPI_Port">
        <operation name="Get_Item_ETA_Date">
            <input name="Get_Item_ETA_Date" message="tns:Get_Item_ETA_Date"/>
            <output name="Get_Item_ETA_Date_Result" message="tns:Get_Item_ETA_Date_Result"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No">
            <input name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No" message="tns:Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No"/>
            <output name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No_Result" message="tns:Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No_Result"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="Get_Item_Quantity">
            <input name="Get_Item_Quantity" message="tns:Get_Item_Quantity"/>
            <output name="Get_Item_Quantity_Result" message="tns:Get_Item_Quantity_Result"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="GetSalesOrderETA">
            <input name="GetSalesOrderETA" message="tns:GetSalesOrderETA"/>
            <output name="GetSalesOrderETA_Result" message="tns:GetSalesOrderETA_Result"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="MyWSAPI_Binding" type="tns:MyWSAPI_Port">
        <binding xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="Get_Item_ETA_Date">
            <operation xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                       soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/MyWSAPI:Get_Item_ETA_Date" style="document"/>
            <input name="Get_Item_ETA_Date">
                <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output name="Get_Item_ETA_Date_Result">
                <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No">
            <operation xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                       soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/myWSAPI:Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No"
                       style="document"/>
            <input name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No">
                <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No_Result">
                <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="Get_Item_Quantity">
            <operation xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                       soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/myWSAPI:Get_Item_Quantity" style="document"/>
            <input name="Get_Item_Quantity">
                <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output name="Get_Item_Quantity_Result">
                <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="GetSalesOrderETA">
            <operation xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                       soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/myWSAPI:GetSalesOrderETA" style="document"/>
            <input name="GetSalesOrderETA">
                <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output name="GetSalesOrderETA_Result">
                <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="myWSAPI">
        <port name="myWSAPI_Port" binding="tns:MyWSAPI_Binding">
            <address xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                     location="http://test.myapi.local:7947/my/path/here/myWSAPI"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: Is there any kind of authentication you need to perform before sending request?
What happens when you run your code? Any error messages?
Maybe try to run it from console with `curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` so you can check what is happening with your request?

Comment: I add my NTLM authentication in the postman application. @Zenithies

Comment: am i not calling / returning the array properly? Why do I just get "{\"success\":true,\"qty\":[]}"
??? and what does that mean.. Success that I'm accessing the XML document?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the `curl_exec` function returns `false`. But your code returns:

```
$response = ['success' => true, 'qty' => $qty];//$qty is the empty array []
```

So, even if the `curl` fails you will get this answer. You do have a log function so you should go and check the log to see any error messages. Alternatively, for testing purposes you can add the error to `$qtyData` to see the error in Postman:

```
curl_close($soapHandler);
$qtyData[] = $err; // add this line ONLY FOR TESTING
$this->logger->info($err);
```

The error will help you to debug what went wrong with the curl request. One of the things you might want to check is authorization. You are currently using only the following two http headers for your request, but your SOAP service might need authorization tokens of some sort (see the documentation):

```
"Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
"Accept: text/xml",
```

Comment: Hey @Klassiek, that error helped me out quite a bit i think. I'm now getting this error: "{\"success\":true,\"qty\":[\"Curl error: Could not resolve host: na-devapp.mysite.local\"]}"

Comment: Two things, I have to be connected to my vpn to hit the host link. I'm running postman on the machine that's currently connected to my netextender/vpn client. Also, i'm adding my NTLM authentication in postman. Are you thinking i need more authorization like you're suggesting tokens as well?

Comment: I don't know whether you need authentication. Just saying your curl request does not have authentication headers set. I might be confused here, but adding authentication to a Postman request which then runs a scipt that does a `curl` request without any authentication is not going to work if you need this authentication.

Comment: Okay, so i didn't know that... I need to setup a username and password in my curl scripts?

Comment: So something like so: $data = array("username" => "adminuser", "password" => "pwd");
$data_string = json_encode($data); and then in the header array include :         'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))

Comment: I really appreciate your help.. i feel like i made a bit of a step forward since you've responded and i really want to just finish this...

Comment: As I said, I don't know how you should authenticate. It is in the documentation of the SOAP service's endpoint. Do you have documentation for that endpoint?